# itext parse pdf issue with french accents “è” ==> “ì”

Tags: itext7, text-extraction

I have un issue with extraction text.
è ==> ì and other...
My code :

```
public static string ExtractTextFromPDF(string filePath)
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            stringBuilder.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page), strategy));

        pdfDoc.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
        return stringBuilder.ToString();

    }
```

[File to reproduce the problem](https://mvpssii.sharefile.eu/d-s9f431653024e47e1accfb9eca3673312)

Comment: Is there an exception? What is the expected result?

Comment: Hi, can you attach the PDF to reproduce the issue? Your code looks fine

Comment: @Alexey Subach  this pdf https://mvpssii.sharefile.eu/d-s9f431653024e47e1accfb9eca3673312

Comment: Which version are you using? I get the correct output, e.g. `Numéro de facture Compte fournisseur` on the latest `7.1.16` release and `7.2.0-SNAPSHOT` both in Java and C#.

Comment: 7.1.16 too with .Net 5. I get : "NumÍro de facture Compte fournisseur"

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on .NET 5. Can you attach the minima project to reproduce?

Comment: There is nothing special in the PDF that would cause the extracting of the 'é' to fail. Thus, is there possibly something special in your environment? Some special default encoding?